# I have troubleshoot with change View Background to Nav Bar Blur in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, view, collectionview, uiblureffect

I have face trouble to get blur background from the Nav bar Blur Effect into Collection View's View background to visible table view. I am give you a collection view here in the SwiftUI.

```
VStack {


        if pinnedContacts.isEmpty {
             Text("No Pinned Contacts")
                .font(.headline)
               .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .padding(.top, 20)
        } else {
            ZStack {
                
                Color.clear // it won't hide background 
                    .frame(height: 150)
                    .blur(radius: 10) // it worked, but need background color hide 
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .background(Color.clear)
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(pinnedContacts, id: \.self) { contact in
                            VStack {
                                if let imageData = contact.thumbnailImageData,
                                   let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                                    Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                        .clipShape(Circle())
                                } else {
                                    Image("Profile")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                                        .clipShape(Circle())
                                }
                                
                                Text("\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                    .padding(.top, 8)
                                
                                Text(contact.organizationName)
                                    .font(.subheadline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                            .frame(width: 100)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                showContactDetailView(contact)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    
                }
    
  
            }
   
        }
```

I have been stressful researched to see why view cant get rid color background if .clear set. If you change `Color.red`  it will show color fully of view... but why the View cant rid color background if I add blur effect.  let me know if you find issues.

Screenshot:[image]